# Is an eigenvector of the power of a non-singular matrix also an eigenvector of that non-sigular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose a $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$ is non-singular. Suppose $v$ is a eigenvector of  $A^m$, where $m$ is a positive integer. Is it ture that $v$ is also an eigenvector of $A$? If it is true, how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it is false. Take $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. What are the eigenvectors of $A^2$? Are they eigenvectors of $A$ too?

Comment: Yes, they are also eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: If $Ax=\lambda x$, then $A^mx=A^{m-1}(Ax)=A^{m-1}\lambda x=\cdots=\lambda^m x$.

Comment: The question is: if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^m$, is it also an eigenvector of $A$? My example shows that the answer is negative.